ON CONFLICT (...) DO UPDATE - can't match constraint condition
I have table "deferred_task" and an index on it:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_deferred_task_unique_payment_check ON public.deferred_task USING btree (((((payload)::json ->> 'transactionId'::text))::uuid)) WHERE ((queue = ANY (ARRAY['check_payment'::text, 'cash_payment'::text])) AND (done_at IS NULL))

which prevents from duplications. I want to insert new row in that table and override values in case of conflict. Below query returns conflict:
    INSERT INTO deferred_task (queue, attempt, payload, reschedule_at)
VALUES ('check_payment', 1,
        '{"attempt":1,"transactionId":"6ec0a1c1-9d07-4785-8114-b5232dd83c5c","expectedStatuses":null}'::jsonb,
        '2024-09-04 11:01:10');

[23505] ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "idx_deferred_task_unique_payment_check"
Detail: Key (((payload::json ->> 'transactionId'::text)::uuid))=(6ec0a1c1-9d07-4785-8114-b5232dd83c5c) already exists.

I tried with condition ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE but no luck.
Either this:
INSERT INTO deferred_task (queue, attempt, payload, reschedule_at)
VALUES ('check_payment', 1,
        '{"attempt":1,"transactionId":"6ec0a1c1-9d07-4785-8114-b5232dd83c5c","expectedStatuses":null}'::jsonb,
        '2024-09-05 11:01:10')
ON CONFLICT (((((payload)::json ->> 'transactionId'::text))::uuid)) DO UPDATE SET reschedule_at = '2024-09-05 11:01:10';

or this:
INSERT INTO deferred_task (queue, attempt, payload, reschedule_at)
VALUES ('check_payment', 1,
        '{"attempt":1,"transactionId":"6ec0a1c1-9d07-4785-8114-b5232dd83c5c","expectedStatuses":null}'::jsonb,
        '2024-09-05 11:01:10')
ON CONFLICT (((((payload)::json ->> 'transactionId'::text))::uuid))
WHERE ((((payload)::json ->> 'transactionId'::text))::uuid) = ('6ec0a1c1-9d07-4785-8114-b5232dd83c5c') DO UPDATE SET reschedule_at = '2024-09-05 11:01:10';

works. In both cases I'm getting error
 [42P10] ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
    DO UPDATE SET reschedule_at = '2024-09-05 11:01:10';

I'm running out of ideas how to write condition for ON CONFLICT (...). Can anyone help me?

You have to use the exact same WHERE condition in the ON CONFLICT clause and the partial index.
